# Multisite and alias suffix

Tags: multi-sites

I am actualy working on a Drupal multi-site environment and I am stuck within a alias suffix problem.

I made a setup like this in my sites.php file for the multi-site alias names.

```
$sites['example.example.de'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-ref.example.example.de.vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-tst.example.example.de.vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-dev.example.example.de.vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
$sites['tp-local.example.example.de.vwp'] = 'example.example.de';
```

My VHost Config file is the following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/seu/xampp/htdocs/iptp"
  ServerName example.example.de
  ServerAlias tp-ref.example.example.de/vwp tp-tst.example.example.de/vwp tp-dev.example.example.de/vwp tp-local.example.example.de/vwp
</VirtualHost>
```

The host file contains the following lines.

```
127.0.0.1 example.example.de
127.0.0.1 tp-ref.example.example.de
127.0.0.1 tp-tst.example.example.de
127.0.0.1 tp-dev.example.example.de
127.0.0.1 tp-local.example.example.de
```

The URL example.example.de works without any problems; when I am trying to open one of the other URLs, I could open the page, but Drupal seems to have a problem with the path.
For example, if I want to open the URL "tp-ref.example.example.de/vwp", Drupal trys to load all CSS and JavaScript files from tp-ref.example.example.de, but it should load it from tp-ref.example.example.de/vwp.

I think this is a base path problem. Does Anyone have an idea about how fix this?

The comment shown in the sites.php is the following one. I used it to edit the sites.php file.

```
/*        
 * URL: http://dev.drupal.org
 * $sites['dev.drupal.org'] = 'example.com';
 *
 * URL: http://localhost/example
 * $sites['localhost.example'] = 'example.com';
 *
 * URL: http://localhost:8080/example
 * $sites['8080.localhost.example'] = 'example.com';
 *
 * URL: http://www.drupal.org:8080/mysite/test/
 * $sites['8080.www.drupal.org.mysite.test'] = 'example.com';
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're loading all these sites from one directory: 'example.example.de'. You only have one site and therefore one settings.php file and ONE base path which defaults to the root domain.

To do what you'd like to do you'd actually need to multisite these with separate directories for each site. To the best of my knowledge anyway.